# Is a performance improvement for this query with subselect possible?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, performance-tuning

I have the following table (simplified non-sense example):

```
table fruits:
+-----+---------+-------------+
| id  | fruit   | customer_id |
+-----+---------+-------------+
| 1   | apple   | 1           |
| 2   | pear    | 2           |
| 3   | kiwi    | null        |
| 4   | mango   | 1           |
| 5   | guava   | 2           |
| 6   | kiwi    | 1           |
| 7   | kiwi    | 2           |
| 8   | khaki   | null        |
| 9   | date    | null        |
| 10  | date    | 1           |
+-----+---------+-------------+
```

Fruits can be assigned to a customer (customer_id).
If they are not assigned to a customer (customer_id IS NULL), they are relevant for every customer.

Fruits can occur multiple times with the same name (but for a customer only once), i.e.
such a thing **does not** occur in the table:

```
+---------+------------+
| fruit  | customer_id |
+-----+---------+------+
| apple   | 1          |
| apple   | 1          |
+-----+---------+------+
```

I use the following query to get all the fruits where the customer_id is null or the customer_id matches a certain value (in this example customer_id = 1).
For fruits that occur twice (in this case kiwi and date), I want to get the rows where the customer_id is not null.

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE customer_id = 1 OR (customer_id IS NULL AND fruit NOT IN (SELECT fruit FROM fruits WHERE customer_id = 1))
```

Result:

```
+-----+---------+-------------+
| id  | fruit   | customer_id |
+-----+---------+-------------+
| 1   | apple   | 1           |
| 4   | mango   | 1           |
| 6   | kiwi    | 1           |
| 8   | khaki   | null        |
| 10  | date    | 1           |
+-----+---------+-------------+
```

**Is there a better query (better performing)?**
Thank you very much!

Comment: How bad is the query performance on a 10-row table that you need to improve it? Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's a very simplified example.

Comment: Caution...  The answer to a simplified example may not apply completely to the real case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problematic constructs:  `OR` and `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )`.  This addresses both:

```
    (  SELECT  *
        FROM  fruits
        WHERE  customer_id = 1
    )
    UNION ALL
    (  SELECT *
        FROM  fruits AS f1
        WHERE  customer_id IS NULL
          AND  NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  1
                    FROM  fruits AS f2
                    WHERE  f2.customer_id = 1
                      AND  f2.fruit = f1.fruit ) 
    )
```

`fruits` needs `INDEX(customer_id, fruit)`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to solve this with a single logical hit on the table, keeping the `OR` condition though.  It may or may not work faster.  The solution requires MySQL 8+ as it uses a CTE and the `ROW_NUMBER` function – features introduced in MySQL 8.

```
WITH
  enumerated AS
  (
    SELECT
      *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fruit ORDER BY customer_id DESC) AS r
    FROM
      fruits
    WHERE
      customer_id IS NULL
      OR customer_id = 1
  )
SELECT
  id
, fruit
, customer_id
FROM
  enumerated
WHERE
  r = 1
;
```

The `enumerated` CTE produces a rowset where each instance of `fruit` has a number based on the descending order of `customer_id`, where a null comes last.  The main SELECT filters that rowset further by only getting the rows with the row number of 1.  A row whose `customer_id` is null can get a row number of 1 only when the fruit is the only instance in the set.  In all other cases, the non-null `customer_id` gets number 1.